How do I send an authenticated POST request to an "Organisation restricted" google form in python?
I work for a company that performs a lot of repetitive tasks by hand. Since most of these tasks are being done digitally, I have been doing some python programming in order to make my job much more efficient by automating many of these tasks. The task that I am currently trying to automate involves inputting data into a Google form over and over again. I am trying to create a program that auto-submits these forms via sending a POST request using the python requests library to the /formResponse section of the selected Google form. I have already managed to create a tool that can do this for a normal form however, I am now attempting to do the same thing, but instead using a Google form that is restricted to the organization (i.e. only users of an organization of “@xxxxx.com” can use it). After doing much research, I believe that I need to authorize the POST request before submitting it using some kind of Google token, but I am unsure how exactly to go around doing something like that. Could someone please help me with how to authorize a POST request with the needed permissions to submit a restricted Google form?
I have tried many different ways of passing authorization credentials into the headers of the POST request, but I continue to receive an HTTP code of 401 "Unauthorized". I believe that I am doing the authorization wrong, as my account has permission to access the form, but I have no idea what the issue is. So if someone could give me a full run down on how to do it, I would be very grateful for the help.
Thank you,
SonicDJM

if normally you run it in web browser then use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox (tab network) to see what browser is sending. Maybe first it has to visit login page and get cookies (after logging) and use it in next requests. (using session in module requests)

you have to better describe it. What modules do you use? requests, urlib or maybe Selenium to control real web browser.

if it Google tool then maybe it has some API which allows to access data.

Hey @furas,
Thank you so much for your responses, to answer you questions in order:

@furas

I have actually tried using DevTools in both Firefox and Chrome in order to see what packets are being used to submit the google form. I could not use it on Chrome, as apparently Google put some form of restriction on the Forms site, preventing me from using those tools. Thankfully, I was able to get around this by using Firefox. I was able to collect the packets during the submission of the Google form, but I was unable to find the exact packet that performs the function. Do you have any suggestions on what exactly I should be on the lookout for?


@furas
2. The only module I currently use to interact with the Google form is Python’s requests library, as I follow the “keep it simple” unix and try to only use built-in packages or libraries directly supported by python. I do have some developer libraries from Google, but I intend to use them in order to generate an oauth token to authorize the packet once it has been created.

@furas
3. This was actually the first thing I tried. However, while Google forms have their own api, it is very primitive in comparison to Google’s other apis, with its only functions being to view the document and edit it, nothing about submitting a response.

@furas
I hope this answers your questions and provides some clarity on the situation. Thanks again for your responses, and I hope to hear from you again.
Many thanks,
SonicDJM
